# Redux dispatch does not update state array with new payload object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I decided to add Redux to my pet project (surprise, todolist).

Here's add entry function:

```
const [todoEntry, setTodoEntry] = useState('');

  const addNewEntry = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    // console.log(todoEntry);

    dispatch({

      type: ADD_TODO,

      payload: {

        prodName: todoEntry,
        done: false,
        favorite: false,
        edit: false,
        id: uuid()
      }
    })

    setTodoEntry('');
```

todoEntry comes from another component like that:

```
 <input

 id='standartInput'
 style={{minWidth: '250px'}}
 value={todoEntry}
 onChange={e => setTodoEntry(e.target.value)}
 type='text'
 placeholder='Add new entry (max 55 symbols)' />
```

Also, I use some hooks to manage my state:

```
  const myTodoItems = useSelector((state) => state.todos[0])

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const [data, setData] = useState(myTodoItems);
```

And, finally, the reducer:

```
import { todolist } from "./todolist"
import { ADD_TODO } from '../Store/todoactions'


export const todoReducer = (state = [todolist], action) => {

    
    switch (action.type) {

        case ADD_TODO: {

            const newItem = action.payload

            console.log(newItem)
            console.log(todolist)
            
            return ([...todolist, newItem])
            
        }

        default:
            { return state }
    }
}
```

The issue is:

- todolist exists, I can see at browser console
- newItem exists too, I also can see at browser console

BUT! When clicking on 'Add' button, state is not updated.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Sostate is just an array of items? Looks suspicious to me that you select onlythe first item.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myTodoItems = useSelector((state) => state.todos[0])
```

You seem to be selecting only the first item, so it's not surprising that you don't see the rest.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(myTodoItems);
```

This looks like an antipattern, why do you need a state variable for something that is already tracked by Redux?

You should also use Redux Toolkit, it is not recommended to use Redux directly.

**Edit:**

Thank you for the codesandbox, now the problem is clear.

You are using both Redux and React state to deal with the same data, for instance you add todos through Redux but complete them with React state.
A very important principle in React/Redux is to have a single source of truth, but in your case you have two sources of truth for the todos: the Redux store and the `useState` hook. You use the React state for rendering and initialize it with the Redux state, but then you don't update it when a todo is added, so the UI shows outdated information.

It's fine to use sometimes Redux, sometimes `useState` as long as it is for independent pieces of data, but for the same data, you need to choose.

Remember that everytime you use `useState(initialState)` you create a new state variable/source of truth, which will become different from the initial state. Sometimes this is exactly what you want, but not here.

So I would suggest to remove the `useState` and go through Redux for everything you want to change about the todos (edit them, complete them, and so on).

There are some things you can have as React state (for instance the boolean "are we currently editing this specific todo item"), but then it would be much easier to have a simple `useState(false)` directly in the TodoItem component.

Comment: The problem is useState trying to manage state together with Redux at the same time, right?

But useState is not used inside addNewEntry function

Comment: @АнтонБлаговещенский The main problem is probably that you are only selecting the first element, so even if addNewEntry works, you won't see the result in the UI

Comment: It's necessary :)

Because useSelector returns [[state]] instead of [state], and I have to access to [0] element of this array.

Maybe there is a way to return [state] without additional '[]' around it?

Comment: This looks strange as well: `export const todoReducer = (state = [todolist], action) => {` If todolist is an array, you should initialize the state with simply `todolist`

Comment: Hmm, you're right, that's where these '[]' come from.

Comment: Great, I changed [todolist] to todolist, removed [0], and Items now shows correctly. But the problem is still here: dispatch does not add new object to existing array.

Comment: Did you try to use the Redux Devtools? You can see if your action reached the store and if it changed the state.

Comment: Redux Devtools writes: "No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions".

Comment: But the store exists: I initialized it at index.js: const store = createStore(rootReducer)

Comment: You need to connect the store to the Devtools. Or even better, use Redux Toolkit where everything is already pre-configured and designed to make your life significantly easier.

Comment: I connected the store to Redux Toolkit, and It shows my state like: todos: (pin) [{...}, {...} ...].

At 'Actions' tab, I see:  type(pin): "ADD_TODO" and my new payload object. Nothing more. State is not changing, no errors in console.

Comment: How is the rootReducer defined? Can you create a codesandbox that reproduces the issue? It would be much easier

Comment: export const rootReducer = combineReducers({

    todos: todoReducer,
})

Comment: Guy, I did it. There's no font awesome icons, but it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/mytodolist-2rokps